# unicode character showing wrong in php sql query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unicode

I'm trying a sql query in php. I was getting ????? instead Unicode characters. I gone through Google and stackoverflow, there I have go many solutions I have tried all of them but still not getting proper result. But when I tried all those  ???? gone but I was getting "\u0cb8\u0cc1\u0cb3\u0ccd\u0caf\u0ca6 \u0c95\u0cc6\u0cb2\u0cb5\u0".

```
<?php
    //header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); 

    $con = mysql_connect("host","uname","pass@");
    //mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'" ,$con);
    //mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
    //mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    //mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'"); 
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("db", $con);
    //mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
    //mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM node");


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $output[]=$row;
    }

    //utf8_encode($output);
    print(json_encode($output));
    //print_r $output;
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

commented lines are solutions i tried.

Answer (score 0):

the following line worked well for me when written in **head tag** of the page

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

try it on the first line. it works well for me.